# Jquery hide not working inside .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading the div helpPage into a div inside of index.html. The load works properly on my index.html page. The problem is that once the helppage div loads into index.html the divs under helpSection all appear and do not disappear until I am able to click on one of the divs. What I would like is only the first helpDiv to show and all the others to be hidden if this is not possible just all of the divs to be hidden. I have tried to play with the jquery code but have been unable to successful get this to work.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dmc620/h4Lsjmzd/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="loadHelpHere"></div>
</body>
```

Html Code

```
<div id="helpPage">
    <div id="helpMenu">
         <h4>Help Menu</h4>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="current_page_item justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div1">Help Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div2">Help Section 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="helpSection">
    <div class="helpDiv">
        <header>Help Documentation</header>
        <article>Works!</article>
    </div>
    <div class="helpDiv1">
        <header>Help Documentation content 1</header>
        <article>Help Section 1</article>
    </div>
    <div class="helpDiv2">
        <header>Help Documentation content 2</header>
        <article>Help Section 2</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#loadHelpHere" ).load( 'help.html #helpPage' );
    $(document).on('click', '.justClick', function (e) {
        $('#helpSection div').not(".helpDiv").hide();
        $('#helpSection div.helpDiv').html($('#helpSection div.helpDiv' + ($(this).index() + 1)).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like it's working fine to me. When you click on a '.justClick' it hides all the other divs and replaces the ".helpDiv" with the html from the correct div. If you're looking for it to hide the other help divs when the page loads you need to move it out of the click event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either set `style="display: none"` on each `<div class="helpDiv">` except the first "helpDiv" or put some sort of css like:

```
/* This will target classes containing the string "helpDiv" but not the class helpDiv */
[class*="helpDiv"]:not(.helpDiv) { 
    display: none;
}
```

and then just do something like this for `.justClick`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.justClick', function (e) {

    // This will hide all divs that contain a class matching "helpDiv"
    $('#helpSection [class*="helpDiv"]').hide();

    // Grab the index of the current .justClick
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;

    // Show the corresponding "helpDiv"
    $('#helpSection div.helpDiv' + index).show();

});
```

[jsfiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/h4Lsjmzd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

So either add a CSS class to hide them by default or set them to hidden when the load is complete.

```
#helpSection > div {
    display : none;
}
```

You can either show the default one and remove the content, or instead of replacing the default ones content, just toggle the visibility of the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/pt74q4dk/1/

Answer (score 0):

set style="display:none;" on divs that you would like to be hidden by default, and then $.show them later when you need to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#loadHelpHere" ).load( 'help.html #helpPage' );
    $( "#loadHelpHere" ).find('#helpSection').hide();
});
```

also, you are missing the closing tag of **div#loadHelpHere**